# Is there any method to define a function name from string in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I want to define some functions named 'test_[strings]' to use for pytest, like :

```
testfiles = ['first.py', 'second.py', 'third.py', ... ]

def test_first():
    test_code

def test_second():
    test_code

def test_third():
    test_code

...
```

The test code is all same, so I think it'll be much simpler if I can define pytest functions by using something like for loop :

```
for filename in testfiles :
    func_name = 'test_'+filename.rstrip('.py')
    def func_name() :
        test_code
```

Is this possible in python3? And if it is, could you please kindly let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Why? This seems like a bizarre way to define tests.

Comment: You don't even seem to be trying to create parameterized tests. Just a bunch of identical tests, all with the exact same body, but different names. Are you trying to inflate your metrics by making it look like you have a lot of tests passing cleanly?

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is insufficient. There's several files to test, and I want to make them to individual test cases. The array contains filename. I modified question.

Comment: That sounds like a job for either parameterized tests, or just a bunch of individually written tests. Even if the code in your question worked, it wouldn't test what you say you need to test.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bizarre way to define tests as mentioned by @user2357112, but I guess you can do something like this:

```
testcases = ['first', 'second', 'third']

def test_function():
  print("It worked")

for test in testcases:
  globals()["test_{}".format(test)] = test_function

test_first()
test_second()
test_third()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why you want to do in this way, but you could use Python Object-Oriented to do this.

Firstly, define a class.

```
class Test:
    pass
```

Define your functions.

```
def func1(self):
    print('I am func1.')

def func2(self):
    print('I am func2.')

def func3(self):
    print('I am func3.')
```

Then, inject the functions to the class.

```
testcases = ['first', 'second', 'third']
functions = [func1, func2, func3]

for i, tc in enumerate(testcases):
    setattr(Test, tc, functions[i])
```

Then, you can use the functions with the name from your list of strings.

```
test = Test()

test.first()

# Output:
# I am func1.

test.second()

# Output:
# I am func2.

test.third()

# Output:
# I am func3.
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow. If you define each function separately why bother injecting them into a class? Just define them as methods from the beginning.

Comment: @Selcuk, just showing the possibilities. If you change `functions[i]` in the for-loop to a certain function name, then it will execute the same function.

Answer (score -2):

```
testfiles = ['first.py', 'second.py', 'third.py']
test_code = 'print(\'hello\')'
def test_first():
    eval(test_code)


def test_second():
    eval(test_code)

def test_third():
    eval(test_code)

for filename in testfiles :
    func_name = 'def test_'+filename[:-3]+'():eval(test_code)'
    exec(func_name)
    eval('test_'+filename[:-3]+'()')
```